# scanf() not taking in input

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, gets

So here is my current issue. Scanf() is not actually scanning at specific points in my program, and there isn't any reason why it wouldn't from the programming/logic portion on my part (Well, as far as I can see).

Also, I have an if statement that is also not working, where if I input 31, it should do the conditional. But, it just doesn't.

And to clarify, anytime I switch scanf() with gets() a window pops up saying "LFSR.c has stopped working. . .". So, I can't just make that switch, for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int sigBit = 0;

    int numOfRands;

    unsigned feedBack;

    // Will hold the input
    unsigned int input;
    // Will be the number of taps the user can give.
    int taps[32];

    // Prompts user for an unsigned int
    puts("Please write an unsigned integer.");

    // Places the input into the correct variable.
    // This works perfectly fine. 
    scanf("%u", &input);

    // Prompt user for amount of random numbers they'd like.
    puts("How many random numbers would you like to be generated.");

    // Places the input into the corresponding variable.
    // This scanf never actually happens. It skips over it.
    scanf("&d", &numOfRands);

    // Prompts the use for the taps they wish to use.
    puts("Please give the taps you'd like to use, between the numbers 0 - 32");

    // Scan the taps into the array,
    while(fscanf(stdin, "%d", &taps[i]) == 1)
    {
        // I also tried to just use if(i == 31), but eitherway, it never triggered this
        // conditional statement.
        if(taps[i] == 31)
            {
                sigBit = 31;
            }

        i++;
        puts("Tap stored.");

    }
    puts("Currently, the sig bit is,");
    printf("%d", sigBit);

    if(sigBit == 0)
    {
       taps[i] = 31;
       printf("We placed the sig bit as a Tap.\n");
       printf("%d, %d\n", taps[i], i);
    }

    for(j = 0, k = 1; j < i+1; j = k++)
    {
        printf("The %d tap was, %d\n", j, taps[j]);

    }
    printf("Please input how many random numbers you want to be generated now\n");

    // This is to test if scanf is working or not, and it always triggers so,
    // That means there's an error, right?
    if(scanf("%d", &numOfRands) != 1)
        exit(1);

    printf("We will create %d random numbers for you.", numOfRands);






    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Somebody would need to consume the Enter key, right?

Comment: Look at some of the related questions on the right.

Comment: `scanf("&d", &numOfRands);` ??

Comment: @devnull, so the scanf is receiving a newline from previous line, typed by the user? So, since puts() creates a newline, that's where the issue lies?

Comment: @Dabo, what's wrong with that line?

Comment: @user41836 `&d` is wrong

Comment: Note: Suggest getting in the habit of writing code that checks the result of `scanf()`.  `if (scanf("%u", &input) != 1) Print_error_msg();`

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf("&d", &numOfRands);
```

Do you mean

```
scanf("%d", &numOfRands);
```

?

Comment: You're so very correct that it literally hurts me. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You used address operator twice, with one in input-order string. The correct operator to be used in the string is %d as it resembles int.
%d - int.
%c - char.
%s - string.
and so on...
Anyway - the scanf should be written `scanf("%d", &numOfRands);` rather than `scanf("&d", &numOfRands);`